# Redirect Powershell Status output for form

Tags: powershell, statusbar

I created a form in powershell and I would like to redirect the status that shows in the ISE to a popup.  Currently when I run the script outside of ISE I do not see the status bar, but seeing it would be very helpful.

Here is the function

```
Function Upload-File {

    param (
        $LocalData
    )

Add-PSSnapin ShareFile

#Run the following interactively to create a login token that can be used by Get-SfClient in unattended scripts
$sfClient = Get-SfClient -Name ((Join-Path $env:USERPROFILE "Documents\Sharefile") + "\MySubdomain.sfps")


#upload directory is relative to the root of the account
#get the current user's home folder to use as the starting point
$ShareFileHomeFolder = (Send-SfRequest $sfClient -Entity Items).Url

# Create a PowerShell provider for ShareFile pointing to Personal Folsers\Send

New-PSDrive -Name sfDrive -PSProvider ShareFile -Client $sfClient -Root "\Personal Folders\Send" -RootUri $ShareFilePath

#upload all the files (recursively) in the local folder to the specified folder in ShareFile
Copy-SfItem -Path $LocalData -Destination "sfDrive:"

#Remove the PSProvider when we are done
Remove-PSDrive sfdrive
}
```

When it runs in ISE

[image: Function running in ISE]

Is there a way to redirect that to a pop-up window?

This is the command to call the function

```
 Start-Process (Upload-File -LocalData "$LocalData") -Wait
```

I saw the write-progress command but didn't see how I could apply it here.  Should I be doing something different?

Comment: Why complicate this with a popup? You have a custom form, just add a progress bar to the form to display the status. There are many examples of this GUI progress implementation, right here on SO, on SU, [all over the web](https://www.foxdeploy.com/blog/part-v-powershell-guis-responsive-apps-with-progress-bars.html), and in [Youtube videos](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=B6E2ytPcTIY). To use form stuff in powershell.exe/pwsh.exe you must add them from libraries. The ISE autoloads these, the consoles do not.

Comment: Postanote, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per my comment, you must add form/gui resources/namespaces to the top of your code when running from the consoles, for form stuff to load since they are not auto-loaded as they are in the ISE.

***Note:
You don't need all of the namespaces. I only put these here to make you aware of the most common ones used in PS GUI scenarios.***

```
Add-Type -AssemblyName  System.Drawing,
                        PresentationCore,
                        PresentationFramework,
                        System.Windows.Forms,
                        microsoft.VisualBasic
[System.Windows.Forms.Application]::EnableVisualStyles()


$Form               = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Form
$Form.width         = 400
$Form.height        = 600
$Form.Text          = 'Add Resource'
$Form.StartPosition = 'CenterScreen'

$pbrTest          = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.ProgressBar
$pbrTest.Maximum  = 100
$pbrTest.Minimum  = 0
$pbrTest.Location = new-object System.Drawing.Size(10,10)
$pbrTest.size = new-object System.Drawing.Size(100,50)

$i = 0

$Form.Controls.Add($pbrTest)

$btnConfirm          = new-object System.Windows.Forms.Button
$btnConfirm.Location = new-object System.Drawing.Size(120,10)
$btnConfirm.Size     = new-object System.Drawing.Size(100,30)
$btnConfirm.Text     = 'Start Progress'
$Form.Controls.Add($btnConfirm)


$btnConfirm.Add_Click({
    
    While ($i -le 100) 
    {
        $pbrTest.Value = $i
        Start-Sleep -m 1
        'VALUE EQ'
        $i
        $i += 1
    }
})


$Form.Add_Shown({$Form.Activate()})
$Form.ShowDialog()
```

Answer (score 1):

Found this [Write-progress during Start-process -Wait](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49342705/write-progress-during-start-process-wait) and ajusted it to your scenario. The general idea os to replace the wait with bypass and let a loop run until $process.hasexited:

```
$process =Start-Process (Upload-File -LocalData "$LocalData") -PassThru

for($i = 0; $i -le 100; $i = ($i + 1) % 100)
{
    Write-Progress -Activity "copier" -PercentComplete $i -Status "copying"
    Start-Sleep -Milliseconds 100
    if ($process.HasExited) {
        Write-Progress -Activity "copier" -Completed
        break
    }
}
```

However the status in this case is only a counter, but u could replace it with something real and change the for-loop to this:

```
Do{
write-progress…
}while(-not $process.HasExited)
```